# TSQL: How to update each record with forreign key

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, primary-key

I have a very old table in MS SQL which do not has any Primary key.
Its structure is:

- Document
- Position
- Material
- Quantity
- ..

I want to change that, and put "DOcument" and "Position" as keys of the table. Of course each combination should be unique. For new records this is already done but for the old one the "Position" field is missing.

What i want to do is an UPDATE of any existing record where the Position is NULL with an incrementational number (each time that change the Document change, the counter should start again at 1)

What should be the TSQL sentence in order to do that quickly?

Thank youIT

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CTE` and the ranking function `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Document, Position, Material, Quantity,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Document ORDER BY Document ASC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
UPDATE CTE SET POSITION = RN
WHERE Position IS NULL
```

If you need a specific logic for the order change `ORDER BY Document ASC` to something meaningful.

If you want to see what will be updated you just have to change the update to a `SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Position IS NULL`. That's one of the benefits of a common-table-expression(CTE).